# filenames, directory, text, python folders subfolders

Tags: python, file-io, directory, subdirectory

With help from you i made a script that takes a list of subfolder (/desktop/filme/1,2,3,4,5...) from a folder (/desktop/filme/) and saves the name of each filenames of each subfolder (/desktop/filme/1/fileone, /desktop/filme/1/filetwo, /desktop/filme/1/filethree...) in another folder (/desktop/text/1.txt, /desktop/text/2.txt...). with the txt it work all right, i want it to save it in excel just like i save it in txt, for that i use xlwt. If you have any ideea for making it work with other libray i will try it.

This is the script that saves txt-s:

```
import os
import os.path

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(r"C:/Users/s/Desktop/filme/"):

    for subdirname in dirnames:

        foldere_filme = os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
        numarul_folderelor = foldere_filme.replace("C:/Users/s/Desktop/filme/", "")
        print numarul_folderelor #1,2,3,4,5...
        root_text = "C:/Users/s/Desktop/text/"+numarul_folderelor+".txt"
        fisier_text = open(""+root_text+"", "w")
        for filenames in os.listdir(foldere_filme):
            numele_pt_text = filenames.replace(".avi", "")
            print numele_pt_text
            fisier_text.writelines(
                                "Full Movie: \n\n\nwatch "
                                +numele_pt_text+" online free, \nwatch "
                                +numele_pt_text+" online")
        fisier_text.close()
```

I want to adapt it for excel creation using xlwt or anything else:

```
import os
import xlwt
import os.path

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(r"C:/Users/s/Desktop/filme/"):

    for subdirname in dirnames:
        foldere_filme = os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
        numarul_folderelor = foldere_filme.replace("C:/Users/s/Desktop/filme/", "")
        print numarul_folderelor #1,2,3,4,5...
        wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
        sheet = wbk.add_sheet('sheet 1', cell_overwrite_ok=True)
        for filenames in os.listdir(foldere_filme):
            numele_pt_text = filenames.replace(".avi", "")
            print numele_pt_text
            sheet.write(0,0,numele_pt_text)
            sheet.write(1,0,numele_pt_text)
            sheet.write(2,0,numele_pt_text)
            sheet.write(3,0,numele_pt_text)
            sheet.write(4,0,numele_pt_text)
            sheet.write(5,0,numele_pt_text)
            sheet.write(6,0,numele_pt_text)
            sheet.write(7,0,numele_pt_text)
            sheet.write(8,0,numele_pt_text)
            sheet.write(9,0,numele_pt_text)
            wbk.save("C:/Users/s/Desktop/text/"+numarul_folderelor+".xls")
```

I'll work on it, but i would very much apriciate any help.

Comment: Your code works fine on my computer..

Comment: You should open your file in append mode instead of write mode. Opening a already existing file in write mode deletes the old content, so everytime you write a new filename into your textfile the old name is erased and the new name is written. That leads to the fact that you only have the last filename in the textfile. Change the line where you open the file to `fisier_text = open(""+root_text+"", "a")`

Comment: @ halex: i don't mind overwriting it... @Rohit Jain: what do you mean it works? it saves each file from within each subfolder Desktop/filme/ (eg: /filme/1/movieoane, movietwo, moviethree. /filme/2/movieoane, movietwo, moviethree.) in file 1.txt 2.txt in folder /Desktop/text/?

Answer (score 2):

But why do you open and close the text file for each line? You could do something like this:

```
    numarul_folderelor = foldere_filme.replace("C:/Users/s/Desktop/filme/", "")
    print numarul_folderelor #1,2,3,4,5...

    root_text = "C:/Users/s/Desktop/text/"+numarul_folderelor+".txt"
    fisier_text = open(""+root_text+"", "w")

    for filenames in os.listdir(foldere_filme):
        numele_pt_text = filenames.replace(".avi", "")
        print numele_pt_text
        fisier_text.writelines(
                        "Full Movie: \n\n\nwatch "
                        +numele_pt_text+" online free, \nwatch "
                        +numele_pt_text+" online")
    fisier_text.close()
```

Comment: i reedited the problem... i want to save it like the text file but in excel, i'll work on it, but if anyone have a solution i'l apriciate it. Thank you very very much for the help.